# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition - temperature units

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, weather

How I can change temperature units from Fahrenheit to Celsius on the Weather scope?

Comment: It's actually an old, known issue, see http://pad.lv/1547981

Comment: Thank you for reference but problem is not solved. Language is set to Latvian but temperature show in Fahrenheit (should be Celsius).

Answer (score 0):

The unit of temperature in the weather scope and the weather part in the today scope is related to the language setting of your phone (System Settings - Personal: Language & Text - Display language).

There is only one issue, and this has been reported as a bug already (as pomsky pointed out in his comment), for which however a work-around is available:
Up until OTA-8, choosing English-Canada gave us the chance to have the phone set to English and still showing temperatures in Celsius. Since OTA-9 this is not working anymore.

Work-around, if you want your phone to be set to English using Celsius as unit for temperature: Switch your language to English-Australia.

Comment: Thenk you but it is not good solution for me because my native language is Latvian

Comment: Sorry, @Andris Petrams. It seems I had over-read your native language in your comment above :( Anyway, I know it is not a solution and only a work-around...

Answer (score -2):

Go to your apps scope, click on weather, go to the gearwheel symbol in the upper right corner.

You can find the Celsius setting under 'units.

Comment: Under the gearwheel is only one checkbox for set on location detect. No more options available.

Comment: In that case: add a location. I did as well and now I can change it.

Comment: Checkbox is named "Enable location data" and its switched On. My location is correct detected - country, city, address and no more options available.

Comment: Hmmm thats odd... Maybe there is an update for the app that you have missed?

Comment: Software is up to date

Comment: In the weather app there is indeed an option to switch between units and add locations. The question however is referring to the weather/ today scope, not the application.